# How does a WCF service know what certificate to use to decrypt an incoming security token?

Tags: wcf, security, service, token, wif

I'm implementing a WCF service using .NET 4.5 and token-based security. On the client side, I'm calling `myfact.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken()` with a token previously retrieved from an STS, when I use this channel to make a call to the service, I get the following error (in the WCF service trace):

```
Cannot resolve KeyInfo for decryption: KeyInfo 'SecurityKeyIdentifier
    (
    IsReadOnly = False,
    Count = 1,
    Clause[0] = EncryptedKeyIdentifierClause(EncryptedKey = qDJDOHUxLxDP8/5baRbY6LrnIX2cYLGwC8b9xDQbEfLsYhcowtszecfWK93dFQHBNV+COHSZpKapJlzrbi12QlObuhfpB08vIxrgXCLg69w4PfAq/jzJcK3N16GHHADSE6XT0KVBXQbcwJqyrELLGAc9ve3cnn52EDg6rkVKBNg=, Method 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p')
    ) ', available tokens 'System.ServiceModel.Security.AggregateSecurityHeaderTokenResolver'.
```

I suspect that this is because the service is unable to decrypt the incoming security token, but I do not know why that would be. The certificate is in the LocalMachine\My store, and has an associated private key.

How does WCF locate the necessary certificate, and why would it be failing to locate it in my case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that the service certificate is the one used. When I corrected this (through the `<serviceCertificate .../>` knob:

```
<behavior name="my_service_behavior">
    <serviceCredentials useIdentityConfiguration="true" identityConfiguration="identity">
        <serviceCertificate 
            findValue="..." 
            x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" 
            storeName="My" 
            storeLocation="LocalMachine" />
    </serviceCredentials>
</behavior>
```

Everything started working.

Comment: Hi, I have the some your problem, can you send me complete app.config? I'm not able to fixed this problem from three weeks

Comment: I don't have the app.config available, but you need to make sure that the endpoint has a behavior which references the correct certificate through the <serviceCertificate> knob.